# How can I delete all tables from existings schema a database Oracle12

Tags: oracle

How to remove all tables from Oracle schema? For example, run a cmd script in Windows which creates a connection to the specified schema and then creates different tables and fills them with data.

And how to write a command that would check :

- if there are any tables in the schema,
- create a copy of an existing schema
- to clear the schema from the tables (tables have a relationship)
- to create a new table

if anyone can write such a script, comment on the commands.

thanks.

Comment: the data will be created each time you run tests from the development environment, populate the schema with tables and initial data.

Comment: it is convenient to me to use a script which to start through cmd filling of the scheme and only after that there will be a start of itnegratsionny tests.

Answer (score 2):

I understand mostly everything, except the purpose of creating "different tables" and inserting the same data into them.

Because, to me, it looks like

- export current schema (use the original `EXP` utility or `EXPDP`, Export data pump)
- drop that user

  - which will also drop all its tables, indexes, procedures, ...
- create user once again
- import contents of the previously exported data (use the original `IMP` utility or `IMPDP`, Import data pump)